# How to have a simple remote access to my containers with traefik without changing the visitor's /etc/hosts

Tags: php, apache, docker, production-environment, proxy-server

I want to have a remote access to my containers which are running on a debian server, I am using [Treafik](https://traefik.io/) to do that.

I have access to my server via it ip (192.168.12.28).

My docker-compose file for traefik container:

```
version: "2"
services:
  traefik:
       image: traefik
       command: --web --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
       ports:
       - "80:80"
       - "8080:8080"
       - "443:443"
       volumes:
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
       - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
       networks:
       - webgateway

networks:
    webgateway:
        driver: bridge
```

My docker-compose file for my two tests containers :

```
version: "2"
services:
       app1:
         image: php:7.0-apache
         labels:
         - "traefik.port=80"
         - "traefik.backend=app1"
         - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:app1"
         volumes:
         - ./app1:/var/www/html
         networks:
         - web
       app2:
         image: php:7.0-apache
         labels:
         - "traefik.port=80"
         - "traefik.backend=app2"
         - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:app2"
         volumes:
         - ./app2:/var/www/html
         networks:
         - web

networks:
   web:
       external:
           name: traefik_webgateway
```

For now, I have to add entries in the /etc/hosts file of the visitor (the computer from which I access to my containers) to have access to my containers. The entries :

```
192.168.12.28    app1
192.168.12.28    app2
```

And I have remote access from the url : http://app1 or http://app2.

What I want is to be abble to access to my containers with a url like :

http://192.168.12.28/app1 or http://192.168.12.28/app2

whithout any modification in the /etc/hosts file of the visitor. (I will not oblige my client to change his /etc/hosts file to access to my applications...)

Is it the configuration of the domain name which is not appropriate?

Do I have to change the default traefik config?

Comment: You need to configure DNS, this isn't a traefik or docker problem.

Comment: My host machine dns? if it is this one, what entries do I have to add?

Comment: The DNS server used by your client machine. That's how DNS works.